# How to filter to show data that contain numbers greater or equal to "x"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a google sheet with data that contains a column that is mixed both with text and numbers. I want to filter all to see which have numbers greater or equal to $500,000.

or which column have the format of '$ Volume: $xxx,xxx' that is >= $500,000.

Example of my data column D:

$xx $100.00 Jul 15 2022 Daily $ Volume: $132,707 Volume: 100

$xx $100.00 Jul 15 2022 Daily $ Volume: $500,000 Volume: 100

ADDED LINK TO SHEET:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PhQhkM6JxEJjHhiGIrWzMilwNwupAemrvcBVliRAB_I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) so that the volunteer contributors here have sufficient data, a place to test and the ability to know other important specs of the spreadsheet at a glance.

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: It seems by the fact that you've checked a reply as "Best Answer" that you've now got the solution(s) you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replied over on reddit, but either of these will do it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  FILTER(
   {A2:A,D2:D},
   --REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D,"Volume: (.*) Volume"))
```

or if you want to use your filter views, use this in another column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
   --REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D,"Volume: (.*) Volume")>=500000))
```

Answer (score 1):

To highlight matching rows in the sheet directly, use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A2:E`:

`=regexmatch(Sheet1!$D2, "\$[5-9][\d,]{5,}")`

To extract matching rows to a new tab, **Insert > Sheet** and put this `filter()` formula in cell `A2`:

`=filter( Sheet1!A2:E, regexmatch(Sheet1!D2:D, "\$[5-9][\d,]{5,}") )`

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't understand how you would like to highlight those rows which contain values> = 500000, I chose to highlight them with conditional formatting using this formula:

```
=value(regexextract(D2,"\$\w*:\$(\d*,\d*)"))>=500000
```

[this is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gGcuv_LG9gZ6Q1aws0lyrsXcKTgrFgic8kJUNPxycAE/edit?usp=sharing) to a modified copy of your sheet

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. There seem to be some errors, some values over 500000 are not highlighted.

Comment: I saw ... the formula is wrong with values ​​greater than $ 999,999, basically when it contains 2 commas